# VPN not working after installing Linux

Tags: networking, 14.04, vpn, nautilus-elementary

I have HP G61 laptop. I'm a university student and we have PPTP VPN connection in the university. Yesterday I installed UBUNTU 14.04 LTS but the VPN is not working. I tried to install Elementary os and Linux mint but i found the same problem, so what can i do ?

Comment: Please, give us more details. Witch vpn protocol you use: pptp or l2tp or ..? Do you try to create vpn connection? Whit Network Manager or widthout NM. If you try give us more detail about error.

Comment: I use pptp VPN.... What do you mean with create vpn connection? do you mean configure vpn? if you mean this, yes,i did it ....

Comment: what vpn are y using ? maybe you need to download client for linux if your vpn prouder have that option

Answer (score 0):

I would echo the need for more information.  Basically, in all of the above you will need to install network-manager-ovpn, network-manager-gnome (apt-get should work).  you may need to also apt-get ovpn, but that's probably included in network-manager-ovpn.  Then, you can create in network manager pptp, l2tp, or more likely (I hope) an ovpn the connection.  The others are relatively outdated.  Using the GUI, the creation process is easy so long as you have the correct files which your university should provide in a linux friendly fashion.

Comment: The instructions here are really clear, with pictures...  torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=53

Answer (score 0):

Try with this script

```
#!/bin/bash
function routeadd {
    route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0
    route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0
}
function makepptp {
   echo pty \"pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd\" >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo remotename PPTP >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo require-mppe-128 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo file /etc/ppp/options.pptp >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo ipparam vpn >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
pppd call vpn &
}
if [ -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets ];
        then
        rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
else
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
fi

if [ -e /etc/ppp/peers/vpn ];
    then
    rm /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
else
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
fi
```

In script change you host ip and add network or/and host witch you wish to connect via vpn

Usage:

```
sudo /path_to_script/vpn username password
```

note: set execute permision to script